# How to custom method finish in my activity when it extends baseactivity

Tags: android, android-intent

I created a BaseActivity and in it I custom method finish

```
@Override
    public void finish() {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        super.finish();
    }
```

Now I create a new activity B extends  BaseActivity but I want when I finish Actiivty B I use new animation

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.transtate_out, R.anim.hold_actibity);
```

How I can replace animation when call finish in activity B?
Thank you for watching!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to remove finish method of BaseActivity class and override this finish method in ActivityB class to add custom your animation there, like this:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.transtate_out, R.anim.hold_actibity);
    super.finish();
}
```

Comment: thank you but in other activity I must use   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
Only in B activity I used 
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.transtate_out, R.anim.hold_actibity);
and I did it, I add a new method finish() in BaseActivity and call in B Activity.
Thank for your answer!

Comment: Glad you found a fix. But if i understand correctly, for example if you have 2 Activities that extend BaseActivity and they don't share common code ( overridePendingTransition in your case) then there's no point in having such code in BaseActivity. Better option is to override finish method in each sub classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a var in BaseActivity like

```
int inAnimRes = R.anim.slide_in_right, outAnimRes = R.anim.slide_out_left;

@Override
public void finish() {
    overridePendingTransition(inAnimRes , outAnimRes );
    super.finish();
}
```

then set value to these two variables in B.